# Python Selenium to Scrape USPS

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to create a script to login to USPS website to get a list of incoming packages from [Informed Delivery](https://informeddelivery.usps.com/).

I have tried two methods:

1. Requests
2. Selenium

---

**Requests**

I captured the Login request and imported into Postman. When I sent request, I received error:

```
{
    "actionErrors": [
        "We have encountered an error.  Please refresh the page and try again."
    ],
    "actionMessages": [],
    "fieldErrors": {}
}
```

In the request body, it sends a token value (from login form). The request headers also send a few headers starting with `x-jfuguzwb-`. These look to be tokens of different values.

---

**Selenium**

Even using a headless browser didn't work.

```
LOGIN_URL = "https://reg.usps.com/entreg/LoginAction_input?app=Phoenix&appURL=https://www.usps.com/"
driver.get(LOGIN_URL)
username = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
username.send_keys(USERNAME)
password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys(PASSWORD)
driver.find_element_by_id('btn-submit').click()
```

displays an error saying "Our apologies that you are having issues with your login."

---

There was a Python Module called [myusps](https://github.com/happyleavesaoc/python-myusps) but it has not been updated for a couple years.

Are there any suggestions as to how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Hmm. That's really interesting. I just tried it myself, and it doesn't work. I also tried it with Mozilla Firefox, time.sleep, driver.wait() to no avail.

Comment: What's interesting is that resending the exact same request causes it to produce an error so requests is out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer below has helped me solve automation issues with site logins that shall go unnamed. I recommend taking a look at the user @colossatr0n answer.

> You can use vim, or as @Vic Seedoubleyew has pointed out in the answer by @Erti-Chris Eelmaa, perl, to replace the cdc_ variable in chromedriver(See post by @Erti-Chris Eelmaa to learn more about that variable). Using vim or perl prevents you from having to recompile source code or use a hex-editor. Make sure to make a copy of the original chromedriver before attempting to edit it. Also, the methods below were tested on chromedriver version 2.41.578706.

[Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver)

Comment: YES! This fixed problem. Replacing `$cdc_` with `$XXX_` fixed the problem completely

Answer (score 1):

A bit of more information about your usecase and the error *Our apologies that you are having issues with your login*
 which you are seeing would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way. However, I was able to send a character sequence to both the *username* and *password* field and invoke `click()` on the <kbd>Sign In</kbd> button using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors):

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://reg.usps.com/entreg/LoginAction_input?app=Phoenix&appURL=https://www.usps.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#username"))).send_keys("Bijan")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#password").send_keys("Bijan")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button#btn-submit").click()
  ```
- Using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://reg.usps.com/entreg/LoginAction_input?app=Phoenix&appURL=https://www.usps.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='username']"))).send_keys("Bijan")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='password']").send_keys("Bijan")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='btn-submit']").click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: usps]

Comment: The problem is not waiting for the element to be callable.  I ran two versions of this. One auto-filled in the fields (even used `ActionChains` and `send_keys(Keys.TAB)`/`send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` to simulate going through the fields naturally. The other version opened the page in via webdriver as well but I entered the credentials manually. The first method returned error "Our apologies that you are having issues with your login". The second worked fine.

Comment: I compared the POST requests in both and the only difference besides the hidden token in form, was a difference in the Headers: `x-jfuguzwb-f`,`x-jfuguzwb-b`,`x-jfuguzwb-a`,

Comment: @Bijan About you first comment, the waiter wasn't about _waiting for the element to be callable_ but for waiting for the element to be **`clickable`**. Using `ActionChains` would have been an overkill. About your second comment, I would avoid any comparison between _Selenium_ and _Requests_ as that would be a bigger topic much beyond the scope of this question. Did you happen to execute the codeblocks from my answer? Can you update me the status please?

Comment: Your codeblock also returned the same login error (when they detect automation). I actually emailed you about this a couple weeks ago with extreme level of detail.

Comment: @Bijan Not sure what you meant by `"they detect automation"`. I have run through the home page HTML of the application. The minor hurdles can be easily overcome using the code in my answer.

Comment: I changed username/password to mine and after Sign In is clicked, it returns an error `Our apologies that you are having issues with your login. We recommend that you restart the current browser and try logging in again........ We do not recognize your username and/or password. Please try again.`. If I login with an actual wrong password, the error is just `We do not recognize your username and/or password. Please try again.`.

Comment: Here are my test cases (FYI I am using your code as the basis for all this)
1) Use Python/Selenium to open USPS page, fill credentials, and push submit: Returns error
2) Use Python/Selenium to open USPS page, fill credentials, but I manually push submit: Returns error
3) Use Python/Selenium to open USPS page, I manually fill credentials, click Sign In via Python: Returns error
4) Use Python/Selenium to open USPS page, I manually fill credentials and press Sign In: Logs in perfectly.

Comment: @Bijan they may be using Javascript experimental technology with `navigator.webdriver` which can detect if the browser is automated (`navigator.webdriver` is set to true on selenium) and block it.

Comment: @AnnaNevison The solution you commented under already adds the experimental options to disable `enable-automation` and turn off `useAutomationExtension`

Comment: @Bijan that doesn't always work because there is a flag in the chrome driver binary that websites can detect and block

Comment: I even added code to change `Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument` to change navigator.webdriver to undefined and still same thing

Comment: @AnnaNevison If you look at the question body OP's main [**bounty**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) concern was **to create a script to login to USPS website** and as far as _Selenium_ is concerned I think the steps till invoking a successful `click()` on the **Sign In** button should suffice. Now, if _ChromeDriver_ driven _Chrome_ browser is getting detected, that's a all together a different issue and must be addressed through a different discussion. I will be happy to write another story on _Chrome browser getting detected_ :)

Comment: @DebanjanB but the web driver is being imported by `selenium` so it does fall within the bounds of the question he's asking- and if the script does not work because `selenium` is importing a web driver that has something that can be detected then bounty concern is not met.

Comment: @AnnaNevison I'm still not sure how you concluded that the _script does not work_ and _bounty concern is not met_. I'm sure if you have a deeper look into the question the original concern is about **to create a script to login to USPS website** which is a legitimate bounty question and definitely not about the error post the invocation of `click()` on the _Sign In_ button which won't be reproducible ever unless you have a valid set of credentials which OP didn't provide within the question. Question for you: 1) Were you able to reproduce the error _Our apologies that you are having issues..._